# Что делать при получении сообщения «Вопросы/ответы участника с данной учётной записью больше не принимаются»?

Tags: поддержка, faq, запрет-публикаций

Прежде чем снова пытаться отправить вопрос, который вы собирались задать,

### [ПРОЧИТАЙТЕ ПРЕДСТАВЛЕННУЮ НИЖЕ ИНФОРМАЦИЮ](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5150/6).

При попытке задать вопрос вы можете получить следующее сообщение:

> Вопросы участника с данной учётной записью больше не принимаются. Более подробно см. в [Справке](/help/question-bans).

Аналогично для ответов:

> Ответы участника с данной учётной записью больше не принимаются. Более подробно см. в [Справке](/help/answer-bans).

- Почему я вижу данное сообщение?
- Учитываются ли удалённые сообщения?
- Блокировка публикации вопросов/ответов и временная блокировка — это одно и то же?
- Как избежать блокировки публикации вопросов?
- Как долго действует блокировка? Что сделать, чтобы снять блокировку? Каким образом повторно активировать учётную запись?
- Могу ли я просто создать новую учётную запись?
- Я задам вопрос на Stack Overflow на английском или Мете, а потом вопрос перенесут на подходящий сайт!
- Блокировка действует также и на Мете?

> Более подробно о [блокировке вопросов](/help/question-bans) и [блокировке ответов](/help/answer-bans) см. в [Справке](/help).

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса: «[What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/)»</sub>

Answer (score 9):

### Почему я вижу данное сообщение?

Как указано в разделе [Тур](/tour), Stack Exchange представляет собой сеть *сайтов вопросов и ответов*, а не форумов для дискуссий. Соответственно, сообщения должны обладать определённой ценностью для будущих посетителей сайта. С этой целью вопросы и ответы низкого качества блокируются, что также помогает исключить [злоупотребление просьбами о помощи](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/), из-за которого участники могут уйти из сообщества. Блокировке подлежат сообщения от участников, которые:

- пишут обрывками фраз;
- не проводят хотя бы базовое предварительное исследование проблемы самостоятельно;
- не могут чётко сформулировать, что они пытаются сделать.

Если с IP-адреса или учётной записи уже отправлялись сообщения *очень* низкого качества, то вопросы и/или ответы из аналогичного источника будут блокироваться [автоматическим фильтром](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56817/can-we-prevent-some-of-the-low-quality-questions-from-entering-our-system/60294#60294).

Внутренние правила фильтра сохраняются в тайне, чтобы предотвратить его обход. Фильтр частично основывается на количестве голосов «против», полученных от других участников. Если другие участники систематически дают низкую оценку вашим сообщениям, подумайте над возможными причинами.

Когда вопросов или ответов низкого качества станет слишком много, возможность публикации новых сообщений будет заблокирована и вы увидите сообщение об ошибке.

### Учитываются ли удалённые сообщения?

Негативная реакция на сообщение (сообщение получило голоса «против» или было закрыто) учитывается при блокировке учётной записи, **даже если сообщение удалено.** По возможности старайтесь исправлять сообщения, вместо того чтобы удалять их.

Кроме того, факт удаления вопроса также учитывается при блокировке, [если с момента публикации прошло менее 30 дней](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91956/i-apparently-got-question-banned-for-deleting-some-of-my-old-zero-upvoted-quest/97720#97720), а другие участники уже потратили время на ответы или модерирование.

Наконец, [удалённые ответы](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105116/sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-answers-from-this-account/105119#105119) всегда учитываются при автоматической блокировке новых учётных записей.

Проблема заключается не в наличии удалённых сообщений, а в том, что если сообщество или вы сами удаляете значительную часть сообщений, то это значит, что они не соответствуют правилам сайта. Подобные сообщения отнимают время участников на чтение, редактирование или [ответы](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74466/does-systematic-self-deleting-need-to-be-prevented/74471#74471). Именно поэтому удалённые сообщения [учитываются](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86982/should-i-avoid-deleting-my-questions/87029#87029) в фильтре наряду с другими факторами.

Имейте в виду, что, возможно, с вашей учётной записью связано много удалённых сообщений, в том числе [старых сообщений с низким рейтингом, которые были удалены автоматически](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year). Такие сообщения видны только модераторам.

### Блокировка публикации вопросов/ответов и временная блокировка — это одно и то же?

Нет. Временная блокировка назначается вручную и является [временной мерой наказания](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/), при котором участник не может задавать вопросы и отправлять ответы. За счёт временного снижения репутации до 1 балла репутации участник также лишается всех остальных привилегий, в том числе возможности комментировать и голосовать. Информация о временной блокировке открыта для других участников.

Блокировка сообщений применяется автоматически и применяется только к возможности публикации вопросов или ответов. Другим участникам она не видна.

### Как избежать блокировки публикации вопросов?

Пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь со [справкой](/help), в частности разделы «[Как задавать вопросы](/help/asking)» и «[Наша модель](/help/stackexchange)». Изучите имеющуюся информацию по проблеме и самостоятельно поищите ответ, прежде чем задать вопрос. Приложите усилия, чтобы написать качественный вопрос.

Предполагается, что все вопросы будут обладать определённой ценностью для будущих посетителей сайта. Если вы не получаете ответы на *большую часть* вопросов, получаете голоса «против», ваши вопросы закрывают или удаляют, значит, они не соответствуют требованиям качества или правилам сайта. Постарайтесь разобраться в причинах и учитесь на допущенных ошибках. Не нужно пытаться отправить один и тот же вопрос снова и снова.

Чтобы разобраться, что такое «хороший вопрос», обратите внимание на следующие разделы:

- [Как задавать вопросы](/help/how-to-ask);
- [Как написать идеальный вопрос](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), автор: Джон Скит;
- [Искусство задавать вопросы](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html), автор: Эрик С. Рэймонд;
- [Добиваемся ответов](http://www.mikeash.com/getting_answers.html), автор: Майк Эш.

Полезная информация по форматированию:

- [Справка по форматированию](/editing-help)
- [Как форматировать блоки кода](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)
- [Песочница форматирования](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) для тренировки.

### Как долго действует блокировка? Что можно сделать, чтобы снять блокировку? Каким образом можно повторно активировать учётную запись?

Автоматическая блокировка не имеет срока действия, то есть нельзя просто переждать какое-то время. Если ничего не предпринять, у вас больше не будет возможности отправлять сообщения. **Единственный способ снять блокировку — внести положительный вклад в сообщество другими способами**.

*Модераторы не могут снять блокировку.*

**Перед тем как предпринять какие-либо действия, *исправьте отправленные сообщения!*** Как отмечено выше, при блокировке голоса «против» учитываются. Поэтому лучший способ поднять рейтинг сообщения — это исправить все замечания, выявленные другими участниками. Были ли ваши предыдущие вопросы непонятными? Из вопросов не ясно, какие усилия вы предприняли самостоятельно? Вопросы были плохо сформулированы, озаглавлены, отформатированы, были слишком длинными или короткими? **Исправьте недочёты!**

Обратите внимание: в советах выше акцент сделан на исправление. **Не удаляйте сообщения.** Как указано выше, удалённые вопросы (если с их публикации прошло менее 30 дней) всё равно учитываются при блокировке вопросов. Удаление сообщений не поможет снять блокировку — поможет только исправление недочётов! В некоторых случаях [вы можете увидеть список](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13193/how-do-i-find-questions-or-answers-that-ive-deleted/13203#13203) вопросов и ответов, которые вы удалили.

Если для вас заблокирована возможность задавать вопросы, значит, необходимо написать несколько качественных ответов, за которые проголосуют другие участники сообщества. Это [может](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68884/why-i-cant-ask-questions/68885#68885) помочь снять блокировку вопросов, но гарантировать это невозможно, так как внутренние правила фильтра держатся в тайне.

Если вы *абсолютно* уверены, что блокировка наложена по ошибке, напишите нам письмо, воспользовавшись ссылкой «связаться с нами» внизу страницы. Учтите, что повторная активация заблокированных учётных записей [не является нашей приоритетной задачей](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62373/better-explanation-when-account-is-blocked/62374#62374).

### Могу ли я просто создать новую учётную запись?

Нет. Автоматическая блокировка выполняется на [более низком уровне, чем учётная запись](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72180/clarify-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this-account-error/76167#comment-174366).

### Я задам вопрос на Stack Overflow на английском или Мете, а потом вопрос перенесут на подходящий сайт!

Перенести вопрос [невозможно](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102293/block-migration-if-user-is-suspended-question-blocked-at-destination), если на целевом сайте для учётной записи заблокирована возможность задавать вопросы. Вопрос просто будет закрыт как не соответствующий тематике.

### Блокировка действует также и на Мете?

Да, но при этом для расчёта автоматической блокировки [снижен](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123068/152859) порог голосов, потому что на Мете участники чаще голосуют «против».

### У моей учётной записи хорошая репутация. Почему она заблокирована?

Блокировка также выполняется по IP-адресу. Такое может произойти, если вы работаете с общего компьютера или из общественной сети, в которой один и тот же IP-адрес предоставляется нескольким конечным пользователям. Блокировка в отношении одного из пользователей распространяется на всех, кто получает доступ к сайту с того же IP-адреса.

Для снятия блокировки зайдите на сайт, используя другой IP-адрес.

Comment: `Блокировка в отношении одного из пользователей распространяется на всех, кто получает доступ к сайту с того же IP-адреса.` — забавно, особенно в век поголовного NAT-ирования.

Comment: Если использовать VPN - можно обойти идентификацию по IP-адресу.

Comment: "Блокировке подлежат сообщения от участников, которые:
пишут обрывками фраз;
не проводят хотя бы базовое предварительное исследование проблемы самостоятельно;
не могут чётко сформулировать, что они пытаются сделать." А можно ссылку на раздел справки где это указано?

Comment: @Anamnian Пожалуйста, посмотрите на сам вопрос — это перевод FAQ–вопроса написанного сообществом на основе справки, написанной сотрудниками, отредактированной модераторами. В конце вопроса есть ссылки на два раздела справки. Пожалуйста, посмотрите на них. Вероятно, слово в слово формулировку вы не встретите, но смысл должен быть один.