# Обрезалась ссылка при закрытии вопроса как дубликата существующего

Tags: дефект, комментарии, ссылки, дубликаты

При инициации закрытия вопроса https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5584/176217 как дубликата другого вопроса [Что делать при получении сообщения «Вопросы/ответы участника с данной учётной записью больше не принимаются»?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5149/176217) ссылка в автоматически сгенерированном [комментарии](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5584/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b4-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-15-%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b#comment21217_5584) обрезалась.

> [image: обрезана ссылка]

То, что ссылка могла быть получена из строки браузера не должно влиять на автоматически сгенерированный комментарий, т.к. механизм закрытия как "дубликат" корректно отработал в плане поиска вопроса, но сбойнул на стадии формирования комментария.

Вопрос на MSE: [Auto-generated link to duplicate truncated in the comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303001/339911)

Comment: Кстати, вы могли отредактировать этот автоматический комментарий.

Comment: @NickVolynkin но надо же решить саму проблему. К тому же, если закрывать как дубликат из очереди проверок, то о том, что надпись сломалась, можно и не узнать

Comment: @АлексейШиманский так не спорю, плюс поставил.

Comment: @NickVolynkin не плюс, а лайк! :D

Comment: @АлексейШиманский "на вопросе плюс, два лайка, класс и подмигивание."

Comment: Подмигивание будет от тех кто хочет познакомиться с ТС чтобы вместе программировать в императивном стиле.

Comment: Так. Хватит тут заигрывать под дефектом :) @Nick, не царское это дело - автосгенерированные комментарии вручную править.

Comment: Не нужно добавлять title в сам URL ссылки, и всего делов.

Comment: @vp_arth **кому** не нужно?

Comment: @alexolut, алгоритму, разумеется

Comment: Я понял почему это происходит. После url-кодирования ссылка на вопрос с длинным заголовком просто не влазит в лимит размера комментария и обрезается вместе с последней скобкой. Надо вместо неё вставлять такую ссылку, какую выдаёт функцию "поделиться".

Comment: Аналогичная ситуация [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/911185/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%87%d1%91%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be?noredirect=1#comment1498929_911185)