# Доступ к удаленным вопросам

Tags: поддержка, удаление-вопросов

Я не успел прочитать всю инфу с предыдущих вопросов - https://stackexchange.com/users/22839002/juniorwebprogrammer?tab=inbox. Как просмотреть ответы и комментарии к удаленным вопросам?

Пытался ввести https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=deleted%3A1 , но вопросов пользователя `juniorwebprogrammer` не нашел. Но они есть - https://stackexchange.com/users/22839002/juniorwebprogrammer?tab=inbox.

Comment: Посмотреть свои собственнные удалённые посты можно с помощью [deleted:1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=deleted%3A1) в поиске. Посмотреть чужие удалённые посты нельзя

Comment: «но вопросов пользователя juniorwebprogrammer не нашел» — значит это был какой-то другой juniorwebprogrammer, а не вы.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как работает удаление? Что может стать причиной удаления сообщения и что представляет собой процесс удаления? Каковы критерии для удаления?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2293/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%

Comment: @αλεχολυτ у вас ссылка побилась

Comment: @user207200 это [давно известная проблема](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5585/176217)