# Что такое "Блокировка пользователей"?

Tags: поддержка, блокировка

Я здесь новичок. Задал три интересующих меня вопроса по программированию на Java в течении недели. Хотел четвертый задать, и меня оповестила система, что мои вопросы не интересны участникам (хотя с какой стати меня должно это волновать) и вышло предупреждение, что я могу быть заблокирован и уже теперь ограничен в задавании вопросов.

Серьёзно? Я правильно перевёл предупреждение?

Answer (score 11):

Вы всё правильно поняли. Система поощряет тех, кто задаёт интересные вопросы и даёт полезные ответы. Кого это не волнует — ну, получают пенальти, в местных терминах — question ban, ограничение на число задаваемых вопросов.

Вероятно вы получили блокировку из-за этого вопроса: [Почему не выводится параметр метода?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1004999/213987) думаю, что часть минусов была за код картинкой.

Вы, возможно, знаете, что программисты пишут код 10% времени, а 90% времени читают свой/чужой. Код оформленный картинкой читать сложнее, скопировать в ответ его нельзя, а потому приходится перенабирать заново...

Вы своими действиями усложняете отвечающим возможность дать ответ, поэтому неудивительно, что часть участников выражает мнение при помощи минусов и голосов за закрытие.

Система считает закрытые и заминусованные вопросы плохими и налагает за них участникам штрафы. Автоматически. Ничего личного.

Подробнее:

- [Почему блокируются вопросы с моей учетной записи?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans)
- [Что такое заблокированное сообщение?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/locked-posts)
- [Что делать при получении сообщения «Вопросы/ответы участника с данной учётной записью больше не принимаются»?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5149/213987)