# Как бороться с троллями?

Tags: обсуждение, блокировка

Я задал абсолютно нормальный вопрос по типизированным файлам в Delphi. Ему сделали -2, после чего для моей учётной записи заблокировали возможность задавать вопросы. Внимание, вопрос: почему сообщество Delphi обижено на жизнь, и почему я должен отвечать за их тяжёлое детство?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что делать при получении сообщения «Вопросы/ответы участника с данной учётной записью больше не принимаются»?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5149)

Comment: Те, кто поставил минусы скорее всего не тролли. Минусы — это лишь субъективная оценка вашего вопроса конкретными участниками. Обычно минусы ставятся, если ваш вопрос не соответствует стандартам качества.

Comment: @insolor сомнительный дубликат, автор ведь не спрашивает, что делать с блокировкой

Comment: @andreymal возможно. Но в любом случае нельзя дать ответ на вопрос в текущем виде, потому что вопрос риторический, и скорее всего его имеет смысл закрыть. Но я решил, что продуктивнее дать инструкцию что делать с блокировкой возможности задавать вопросы. В общем, отозвал свой голос за закрытие, комментарий пусть остается.

Comment: Возможно речь надо вести о правилах блокировки (поробуйте объяснить сообществу почему они не адекватные), а не о тяжелом детстве?

Comment: "TStringList нет в делфи" - дальнейшее он договаривал в пустоту.

Answer (score 12):

ТС далеко не так безобиден как может кому то показаться. Наказали его за комментарии типа:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Oy  ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Нет, минусов наставили за вопрос о типизированном файле)

Comment: Минусы за ответы не имеют отношения к наказанию - очевидно

Comment: Молодец, кстати, что вырвал коммент из контекста) После просмотра полной версии у всех отпадут вопросы :)

Comment: @BlackMan никакой контекст не даёт права писать комментарии такого рода.