# Ну и как мне вернуть возможность задавать вопросы?

Tags: дефект, поддержка, локализация, вопросы, заблокированные-вопросы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Мне больше заняться по вашему нечем кроме как редактировать 62 заданных мной вопроса за 5ть слишним лет ?Что я там править должен ? Могу удалить их все. По факту бан ни за что учётке выдали..

Comment: На что вы жалуетесь? Опишите подробнее. По этим 2 строкам не понятно ничего.

Comment: ну видимо за отсутствие способности понятно сформулировать свои мысли и нормально задать вопрос. Впрочем, за бестолковость тут не банят.

Comment: Я добавил.. никаких точных инструкций, что конкретно исправлять я не вижу.. К некотрым вопросам  у меня вобще рабочего кода небыло... были только скрины... если бы я знал, что влепят бан..  я бы вобще не задавал подобного рода вопросы... Как что не спросить.. то то не так, то  код аодавай который  можно запустить... а его нет.. короче ладно.. Тут же  сеньёры сидят через одного, попробуй только что-то базовое спроси

Comment: @ZdraviSmisl а я вижу - [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIG7p.png), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLLhd.png), [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HF7Sk.png), [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PciFq.png), [5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7NVK.png), [6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvRYf.png)... Гора вопросов по типу "почему это не так?" с ужасным оформлением и с непонятной лексикой. Наверно, кто-то из модераторов не сдержался. :)

Comment: @Эникейщик *"за бестолковость тут не банят"* - вот как раз за бестолковость человек бан на задание новых вопросов получил, разве нет? )

Comment: @Kromster ну это уже хроническая бестолковость. За такое можно :)

Comment: Отмечу, что удаление вопросов не поможет (и даже ухудшит шансы) снять бан, ибо удаленные вопросы все равно будут участвовать в расчете метрик. Так что только редактирование, улучшение уже имеющихся вопросов и качественные ответы могут помочь.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что делать при получении сообщения «Вопросы/ответы участника с данной учётной записью больше не принимаются»?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5149/337980)

Answer (score 3):

О том, как вернуть как раз указано в упомянутом тексте.

Заодно, добавил необходимые переводы:

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18395
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18612

Можете посмотреть текст по ссылкам. Будет доступно на сайте в новых сборках. Текущая rev 2023.2.17.43248