# Как работают `блокировка вопросов` на сайте stackoverflow?

Tags: поддержка, предложение

Я получил 2 недели назад блокировку вопросов. Осознав свою глупость, я воспользовался рекомендации сайта и редактировал свой вопрос так, чтобы он подходил к рекомендации сайта stackoverflow. Но блокировку не сняли и я зашел в тупик... Так же я не понимаю данные слова в объяснение, как снять блокировку с вопросов:

> Как снять блокировку вопросов?
> Блокировка снимается системой автоматически, когда положительный вклад пользователя перевешивает отрицательный рейтинг предыдущих сообщений.

Как автоматически? Какие вопросы нужно редактировать? Нужно редактировать все вопросы или же где отрицательный рейтинг? Сколько нужно заработать положительного рейтинга, чтобы снять блокировку? Что делать, если пользователи больше не заходят на вопрос, и это физически невозможно будет сделать?
**У меня много вопросов, но на них нету ответов!**
Вот ссылка на мой вопрос: [Необходима помощь с изменением времени при нажатии на кнопку в Unity](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1533422/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2-unity). Если мой вопрос не достоин 3 репутации, скажите, что мне сделать, чтобы я стал достоин!

Ну а так же я бы мог предложить сделать какую то вкладку "Искупления", где пользователи бы смотрели на вопросы забаненных пользователей и решали достоин ли он разбана или же нет. Проблема в том, что даже если ты исправил все свою ошибки, то другие пользователи не буду заходить на вопрос, которому уже дали ответ. И получается глупому пользователю, которому было просто лень прочитать рекомендации по составлению вопроса на сайте stackoverflow, будет вечно сидеть в бане вопросов, ведь никто не заходить на редактирование вопросы!(Про глупого пользователя, это я про себя, я не пытаюсь не кого не обидеть!)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что делать при получении сообщения «Вопросы/ответы участника с данной учётной записью больше не принимаются»?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5149)

Comment: @PetəíŕdTheLinuxWizard, нет, все же вы не правы.

Comment: А точно осознали за что вообще бан? SO это ресурс, где мы, сообщество, собираем полезное, не только для авторов конкретного вопроса, но и для будущих читателей, ну а вы, наверно из-за погони за репутацией, начали спамить ответы полученные от ChatGPT, зачастую неверные ответы, везде, даже там, в чем не разбираетесь ([пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1535539/220553) - написали полнейший бред, да еще и то, что автор вопроса изначально сделал). Другими словами вы захламляли труд многих, а это не красиво. Если и дальше будете GPT использовать, можете и суровей бан получить.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ всё так, только речь про вопросы, а не ответы. Блокировки давать ответы у этого участника нет. Речь про автобан именно вопросов.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Я осознал, что использовать ChatGPT не правильно, т.к. мои познание не увеличатся и это будет не честно со стороны других учасников сообщество, поэтому было принято решение мной больше не использовать ChatGPT для ответов на вопросы других участников. Сейчас я отвечаю на те вопросы, на которые знаю ответ!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Почему блокируются вопросы с моей учетной записи?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans)

Прошу обратить внимание на то, что никто, даже модераторы, не могут снять такую блокировку. Блокировка накладывается и снимается только полностью автоматически. Если вы отредактировали вопросы, покажите на них ссылки, мы посмотрим. Возможно удастся снять блокировку положительными голосами или переоткрытием этих вопросов. Удалённые вопросы также принимают участие в расчёте рейтинга для блокировки.

Детали работы алгоритмов блокировки находятся в секрете и не подлежат разглашению. Даже я знаю эту систему очень поверхностно.

**UPD:** поздравляю, кажется ваша блокировка снята.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Значит если я удали вопросы с отрицательный рейтингом, то это сможет мне немного помочь?

Comment: @Nymos я как раз написал о том, что нет, не может.

Comment: И что получается делать, просто постоянно редактировать один и тот же вопрос?

Comment: @Nymos почему один? у вас их всего 10, включая 2 удаленных.

Comment: Что насчет удаленных, честно не помню, вот 8 остальных вопросов получается редактировать, как это:https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1533422/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2-unity?

Comment: @Nymos откройте список вопросов своего из профиля, там внизу будет маленькая ссылочка "недавно удаленные вопросы"

Comment: один вопрос восстановил, но другой является просто дубликатом, его тоже надо восстановить?

Comment: @Nymos перечитайте этот ответ, уже ничего не надо.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, что помогли мне с моей проблемы. В будущем, я надеюсь, что больше Вам не принесу хлопот. С уважением к модератору **aepot**!