# Имеет ли место накрутка голосов и что мы с этим можем поделать?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, ответы

### Описание

Есть [вот этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1563379/324730) вопрос. В нем тривиальный алгоритм с циклами:

```js
simpleNum:
for (let i = 2; i < 50; i++) {
    for (let j = 2; j < i; j++) {
        if (i % j == 0) continue simpleNum;
    }
    console.log(i);
}
```

Ну задавший не опытный, может не понимает. Тут ничего особенного.
Но вот конкретно [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1563389/324730) интересен:

> [image]

Другими словами...

[image]

То есть, то, что `Цикл for i выполняет цикл j, потом цикл i++ выполняет цикл j и т.д.` и сразу все встало на свои места?

### А теперь серьезнее

Я думал, как так получилось, что участник отметил этот ответ правильным. И в голову пришло только 1 нормальное объяснение:

- Участники А и Б договариваются помочь друг друга подняться в репутации.
- Участник А задает вопрос.
- Участник Б пишет более-менее подходящий ответ.
- Участник Б голосует за вопрос.
- Участник А голосует за ответ и принимает его.
- Участники А и Б получают репутацию соответственно 12 и 25 и радуются своему остроумию.
- База StackOverflow пополняется мусорными вопросами и ответами.

То, что сообщество голосовало -4 за ответ это особо ничего не меняет. Участник получил 25 - 8 = 13 репутации и скорее всего будет снова так же делать.

### Вопрос

Я хочу узнать, что мы можем делать против такого на данный момент который соответствует правилам сообщества?

Comment: _То, что сообщество голосовало -4 за ответ это особо ничего не меняет_ - на самом деле меняет. Не известна точная формула, однако количество заминусованных вопросов/ответов влияет на возможно стьзадавать новые вопросы и ответы

Comment: @Grundy Вот про это не знал. Можно статью?

Comment: Есть faq по [теме](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5149/176217)

Comment: У автора был вопрос «i и j сразу инкрементируются или нет», и, если не слишком придираться к формулировам, этот ответ даже немножко отвечает на такой вопрос. Он, конечно, заслуженно заминусован за свою корявость, но всё-таки ответ

Comment: *"что мы можем делать против такого на данный момент который соответствует правилам сообщества?"* - русский язык и связность предложений покинули вопрос ..

Comment: Меня больше удивляет, что у ответа рейтинг +2/-9. Кто выдал +2?

Comment: Часто вижу у других и своих вопросов, ответов минуса. Вроде всё изложено, описана проблема, найдено решение. Но кто минуснул и за что, не понятно! Если вы хотите правильности функционирования этого метода реакции на вопрос-ответ, то нужно ввести обязательно указать причину! В форме выбора вариантов, или произвольная форма. Можно в тайне держать ник, но причину минуса показывать. Ну и если в алгоритме минусования появится функция "ПРИЧИНА" то меньше долб.... будут жать её, не разобравшись с вопросом, ответом.

Comment: @FrancNet, этой системе пятнадцать лет. Вы серьезно думаете, что кто-то что-то станет менять? Такие предложения _постоянно_ вносятся, но...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если возникает подозрение на накрутку репутации, или какие-то другие действия, которые могут быть расценены как злоупотребление при использовании системы, правильный вариант - поставить тревогу "требуется внимание модератора" и предоставить достаточно подробное описание ситуации.

Однако, хочу заметить, что репутация участников в обсуждаемой ситуации достаточно низкая (меньше сотни), поэтому даже в случае наличия взаимного голосования вряд ли можно говорить о каких-то серьёзных последствиях и необходимости блокировок, пересчёта репутации и т.п. Ловить надо "рыбёшку покрупнее".

Comment: Или предотвратить "мелкие" :)

Answer (score 5):

"тривиальный алгоритм" - он тривиален для тех, кто знает

Я не вижу тут никакой накрутки. Посмотрите хотя бы на его активность и кто ему отвечает, перед тем как наводить панику

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И то, эти последние 10 баллов я ему подарил...

На SO и ruSO 100500 вопросов я встречал, где отмечают правильным вообще непонятный ответ.

Но конкретно тут скорее всего просто задающий вопрос, не знает как работает система и т.к. до 15-ти баллов у него не было возможности голосовать "За", то он отмечал ответы, желающих ему помочь как принятые (возможно, просто в качестве благодарности, а возможно они ему реально помогли, не охота в этом копошиться)

И сейчас, увидев "добрые" комментарии к своему вопросу, решил отблагодарить человека, который хотя бы решился помочь ему. Ну, или по другой причине

Answer (score 1):

Скажу очевидное:

1. Если с этим что-то "делать", то схема накрутки голосов станет намного незаметнее.
2. Мусорные ответы и вопросы будут создаваться тысячами без всякой накрутки. Вспомните первые курсы универа и начало своего пути на SO - о необходимости форматирования ответа и вопроса узнают не сразу, (я не знаю почему, вроде написана же подсказка, но сам факт) - может быть ленятся просто.
3. Предлагаете вы что? Очередные ограничения вводить? Любые ограничения в первую очередь бьют по честным людям, во вторую очередь по ленивым, и уже в третью очередь по "мошенникам", которые в любом случае придумают простейший способ обхода очередных ограничений.
4. 99% мусорных вопросов и ответов даются участниками с репутацией меньше 200. Я не помню всех точностей, но с низкой репутацией очень ограничены возможности. Например, нельзя голосовать ответу "за" и "против". Поэтому решение, где дали хотя бы подсказку, приходится принимать как решенное (особенно если других ответов просто нет).
5. Единственное возможное решение проблемы "мошенничества" - это внимание модераторов и других администраторов ресурса SO. Но их просто мало, это же волонтеры. Сейчас можно "пожаловаться" на вопрос или ответ, и модератор проверит ответ или вопрос, на который пожаловались.

В общем, мне кажется вы придираетесь просто. Текущая система SO очень сбалансирована, с учетом того что штатных сотрудников (модераторов/администраторов) "на зарплате" очень мало или нет совсем.

Если повысить влияние дизлайков на репутацию, то какое-нибудь непопулярное или нетипичное, но гениальное решение (или плохое настроение некоторых участников) может убить репутацию полностью. У меня есть несколько таких ответов. Сейчас там общее число голосов "за" 75%. Но в первое время почему-то был шквал дизов. Баланс, всё дело в балансе.

Comment: Возможно, на низкой репутации нельзя даже оставлять комментарии и редактировать свой вопрос/ответ. Я не помню где можно посмотреть эти подробности, но факт в том что с репутацией ниже 100 очень тяжело здесь.

Comment: [Начинается все с 15](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges). `Если с этим что-то "делать", то схема накрутки голосов станет намного незаметнее.` - А если заметить и ничего не делать, то в чем смысл?

Comment: @eccs0103 похоже вы не понимаете смысла "баланса". Вы, как и большинство людей, ищете "быстрое просто гениальное решение". Сейчас баланс таков, что все выстроено вокруг порядочности участников, ну и модераторов.

Смена баланса означает смену всей системы и общего смысла этой новой системы. Добавление костылей в текущую систему - это путь в кашу из костылей. Кардинальная смена системы - это автоматическая смена аудитории. Stackoverflow сейчас пользуются миллионы и десятки миллионов.

Сменить систему контроля на "жесткую" - сервис потеряет 90% пользователей. И, возможно, станет платным.

Comment: @eccs0103 а еще смысл в приоритетах. Нет смысла ломать стройную систему лишь для того, чтобы проверить очередную теорию, которая уже много раз проваливалась в аналогичных системах.

Проблема накрутки голосов очень незначительна, и в большей части нивелируется работой модераторов. Я это вижу эту проблему так. 

За репутацию (плюс-минус 20) здесь никто не платит, и смысла в этом очень мало - только для того чтобы пробить некую веху репутации. На постоянке такой ерундой никто не занимается и заниматься не будет.

Comment: @eccs0103 если и вводить какие-то ограничения, то только для выборов модераторов, которые проходят каждый месяц вроде. Но это отдельное обсуждение. Нечестный выбор модератора действительно повлияет на сервис негативно. Хотя что значит "нечестный", если всегда можно позвать сотню знакомых, чтобы они поставили свой голос за тебя? 

Это уже вопрос к неизбежному обходу любых ограничений.

Answer (score 0):

Предложенная схема станет только незаметнее, если вместо мусорного ответа написать что-то реалистичное. Так что мне кажется, что подход неверный.

Comment: Конкретно для этого случая согласен. Я ошибся - не накрутка. Но я немало таких вопросов встречал.