# получил автоматическую блокировку на stack overflow

Tags: поддержка, запрет-публикаций

получил автоматическую блокировку на stack overflow, за то что мои вопросы собрали отрицательные баллы, что теперь делать не знаю. вопросы свои отредактировал, но блкировка не снята. что теперь делать?

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5149/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%92%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8b-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%83%d1%87%d1%91%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b7%d0%b0

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что делать при получении Вопросы ответы участника с данной учётной записью больше не принимаются](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5149/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%92%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8b-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%83%d1%87%d1%91%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b7%d0%b0)